# Azure Website ASP.net WebPages "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-webpages

I've developed an application in WebPages and im hosting the website on Azure. Its giving me the error "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."
I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.
Heres the Web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Webpages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
        </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>

  </system.web>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
            <add invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" name="Microsoft® SQL Server® Compact 4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
    <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>


  <connectionStrings><add name="SQLAzure" connectionString="Data Source=###;Initial Catalog=###;User ID=### ;Password=###;Encrypt=true;Trusted_Connection=false;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

If I remove the assemblyBindings  "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers'" error pops up. Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, you should be able to determine the error by [remote debugging your Azure web site](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/#remotedebug)

Here is another [troubleshooting reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/waws/archive/2014/05/22/azure-web-sites-troubleshooting-server-error-in-application-errors.aspx) if you aren't using Visual Studio

Comment: Thanks. I found out what was wrong. The files in the bin folder were all the previous version so i had to copy the files from GAC to the bin which sorted everything out.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Websites have System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0 and your web.config refers to Version=2.0.0.0.
Yes you can copy the correct version from your GAC to bin , but this is not optimal solution, because you have to upload binaries to Azure and that is not you job.

The best solution is use NuGet package manager.

You can do it from your visual studio 
run the following command in the [Package Manager Console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console) `Install-Package microsoft-web-helpers`